# Create and remove devicetree nodes at runtime for debugging

Tags: kernel-modules, device-tree

I am writing a simple Linux module on an embedded platform. For testing, I can load and unload it with `modprobe` etc., and my `module_init` code gets called.

However, if I want to use the modern `module_platform_driver` way of writing a module, there is no init function anymore, and my probe function does not get called. For this, I would have to modify the device tree (and flash a new image etc.).

Is there a way to force probe a driver? Or can I attach initialisation code when a platform-driver style module is loaded, regardless of device tree entries?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do what you want using "Device Tree Overlays" to dynamically add and remove entries from the device tree at runtime.